# Merge 3 Workbooks into 1 master workbook Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have xls files that I want to merge in a master file called QA.xls, all the workbooks have the same columns. Want for it to look for a specific file in a directory, which names are:
**1. QA_ana  2. QA_carol  3. QA_vane** I found the following code:

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow
Dim Filepath As String
Filepath = "C:\QA\"
MyFile = Dir(Filepath)
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    If MyFile = "QA.xlsm" Then
    Exit Sub
    End If

    Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile)
    Range("A2:D2").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 4))

    MyFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Can you please help me edit that code to use the files specific file names in a specific directory.

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've only got three specific files you want to open, I wouldn't bother looping through everything. Just use:

```
Dim wbkOne as workbook
Dim wbkTwo as workbook
etc

set wbkOne = workbooks.Open("C:\QA\QA_ana.xlsm")
set wbkTwo = workbooks.Open("C:\QA\QA_carol.xlsm")
etc
```

Comment: `Sub combine()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow
Dim Filepath As String
Dim wbkOne As Workbook
Dim wbkTwo As Workbook
Filepath = "T:\NetSpend Supervisors\SHARED QA\"
MyFile = Dir(Filepath)

Set wbkOne = Workbooks.Open("T:\NetSpend Supervisors\SHARED QA\QA_ana.xlsx")
Set wbkTwo = Workbooks.Open("T:\NetSpend Supervisors\SHARED QA\QA_carol.xlsx")
     wbkTwo.Open
    Range("A2:O2").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
        erow = combine.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("combine").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 4))
    MyFile = Dir
End Sub`